# Circular includes in C++ - again

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Test1.h"
#include "Test2.h"

int main(){  
    Test1 t1;
    Test2 t2;

    t1.process(t2);
    t2.process(t1);

}
```

**Test1.h**

```
#ifndef TEST1
#define TEST1

#include "Test2.h"

class Test1 {
public:
    void process(const Test2& t) {};
};


#endif // !TEST1
```

**Test2.h**

```
#ifndef TEST2
#define TEST2

#include "Test1.h"

class Test2 {
public:
    void process(const Test1& t) {};
};


#endif // !TEST2
```

VS2012 says:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
error C2664: 'Test2::process' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Test1' to 'const int'
```

I am pretty sure it's the *circular includes* problem again (I come across it once in a while), but this time I am not sure why doesn't this compile.

Notice: the classes only depend on each other's references, which are of known size. Is it because of the include guards (`#ifndef`), that make one of the Test headers include the other as an empty file?

Comment: Why do you need to include at all? Forward declaration is enough in both `*.h`.

Comment: There are millions of duplicates of this. Make some effort to research the problem before posting.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration), very good explanation. You can use it as a rule of thumb, when deciding whether to forward declare or to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully expand the preprocessor directives and you'll see the problem:  Main.cpp includes Test1.h which includes Test2.h, so `class Test2` will be compiled first, before `Test1` is ever defined, leading to the `missing type specifier` error.  You can probably fix this by forward-declaring `Test1` and saying `void process(const class Test1& t)` rather than just `void process(const Test1& t)`.

Comment: but why do I need a definition of Test1 in Test2, I only use a reference in a method signature; its of known size. I dont even call any methods

Comment: For C++ that's not enough; it doesn't know what `Test1` is at that point, so it doesn't know if it's a type or something else.  Sure, C++ could infer that `Test1` is a type, but that's not how the language was designed.  You have to explicitly say `Test1` is a type before you can use it; either declare the type fully, or forward-declare it as a type.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on doing this, you need to forward declare your class in each .h file so that the compiler knows what it is.

```
#include "Test1.h"

class Test1;

class Test2 {
public:
    void process(const Test1& t) {};
};
```

Comment: Forward declaring `class Test1' allows you to declare pointers to Test1, not implementing references. Also `#include<Test1.h>` does not seem right here.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: What does "implementing references" even mean?!

Comment: Question closed too fast for me to adjust anything.  Oh well.

Comment: @KerrekSB Writing the implementation for `void process(const Test1& t){ .... }`. I apologize for my sloppy language. Mea culpa.

Comment: But why do I have to forward declare Test1, when it's right there - in the included Test1.h ?

Comment: Just read the linked question.  It's explained completely there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put a forward declaration of one of them in the header of the other. If you forward declare Test1 in Test2.h (before declaring Test2), you can remove `#include "Test1.h"` from Test2.h.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference or pointer to a type within a header just try using a forward declaration.

```
// Within stop Test2.h
class Test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `test1.h` and `test2.h` you can use a forward declaration of `Test2` and `Test1` respectively avoiding the includes. Just put `class Test1;` in place of `#include "test1.h"`.

Then include `test1.h` in the implementation file only.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)